# How to insert today's date and disable input if checkbox is checked using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I need today's date to show and be disabled if the new student checkbox is checked.

I tried making a function and adding it to the checkbox on change event, then I tried making a function with a if statement that was supposed to work onclick but it didn't work either.

I expect it to disable the date field and make today's date the enrollment date.

```html
Check if New Student<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" name="New_Student" onclick="document.getElementById('date').disabled=this.checked"><!--If checkbox is checked date box is disabled-->
      <br>
<legend>Enrollment Data</legend>
<label for="sel1">Select Date of Enrollment:</label><br>
<input type="date" name="Enrollmentday" value="EnrollDate" id="date" onchange="checkDate(this);"><!--Gets today's date and puts it as max-->
```

Comment: Disabling is working fine!!

Comment: yes the disabling works but it doesn't put today's date there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the value to the date input. I've commented an alternate way and added extra code that resets the value when checkbox is checked again, Consider the following:

```js
function onCheck(checkbox) {
  var dateElement = document.getElementById('date');
  dateElement.disabled = checkbox.checked;
  if (checkbox.checked) {
    //dateElement.value = new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10);
    dateElement.valueAsDate = new Date();
  }
  else
    dateElement.value = '';
}
```

```html
Check if New Student<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" name="New_Student" onclick="onCheck(this);">
<!--If checkbox is checked date box is disabled-->

<br>

<legend>Enrollment Data</legend>
<label for="sel1">Select Date of Enrollment:</label><br>
<input type="date" name="Enrollmentday" value="EnrollDate" id="date" onchange="checkDate(this);">
<!--Gets today's date and puts it as max-->
```